# Ruby not allowing dynamic strings as an argument

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I have a class already mapped out and in a database through DataMapper and now I'm trying to make my first resource into the database.

I have a class that handles the form data and file stuff. In that class, I'm creating the first resource with `@variables` passed in from the params.  All other args passed into this resource come from `@variables` that have values from the form. In this case, `@url`, the variable in question, is set to a value only a few lines before. Now when I put in the URL:

```
rec = Post.new(
      # more args
      :filename_ogg => @url
)
rec.save
```

This is the killer: Every other line of code in this file is able to access `@url`, through a global variable (`$upload = Upload.new(file)`), except for this resource creator. When it comes to saving the resource, it doesn't go through. BUT, when I replace `@url` with a static string like "RANDOM URL.", it works perfectly. Why?

This had been tested under both MRI 1.9.3 and JRuby 1.6.7.2 (1.9 mode) under Ubuntu 12.04:

```
# #{user} edited out
class Upload
    attr_accessor :file, :filename, :filename_ogg, :status, :title, :desc, :url

    def initialize(file)
        @file = file
        @filename = @file[:filename].gsub(" ", "")
        @filename_ogg = "#{@filename}.ogg"
        #@url = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/#{user}/#{@filename_ogg}"

    end

    def downandup
        # code
    end

    def convert(file, file_ogg)
        # code
    end

    def upload(file_ogg)
        # code
        @url = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/#{user}/#{file_ogg}"

        # title and desc are accessed through $upload.title/$upload.desc
        rec = Post.new(
            :title => @title,
            :description => @desc,
            :author_id => Random.rand(5),
            :time_uploaded => Time.now,
            :filename_ogg => @url,
            :comments_table => Random.rand(10),
        )
        rec.save
    end
end
```

The file runs through fine, but when it comes for DataMapper to put it in the database, it won't go in, but when replaced with the static string, the data gets stored.

Comment: Code. Include some, or we can't tell you what's happening.

Comment: Where is `user` coming from in @url? Can't find it nowhere.

Comment: It's an existing bucket that I didn't want public. I have the `#{user}` replaced with the real thing in the code, but just replaced it with `#{user}` here.

Comment: What exactly is happening? An exception? May you provide a stack trace pls if so?

Comment: Agreed please provide the error message, or unexpected behavior.

Comment: I'll add it here, then in the main question: The file runs through fine, but when it comes for datamapper to put it in the database, it won't go in, but when replaced with the static string, the data gets stored.

Comment: It's definitely a bad idea to: 1) Override `initialize` - use `attr_accessor` for a hash and `before_save` to fill corresponding properties, all getters and setters are defined for you. 2) Omit `include DataMapper::Resourse` 3) Use global properties. 4) Use `new` + `save` instead of a single `create`.
In any case please clarify what the `class Upload` is, a controller? It doesn't look like a DataMapper resource at all.

Comment: `Upload` isn't a DataMapper resource, it's a class that is supposed to clean up the rest of the file it's in. `Post` is the DataMapper resource already defined and in a database.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my editor, and terminal output at the bottom: http://img.ly/system/uploads/005/185/274/original_Screenshot%20from%202012-08-07%2023:37:30.png I was trying to use string escapes, but that doesn't work. Even without them, and I just use `@url`, the same output in the terminal comes out.